# Why does order ASC break offset in WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

I have a function being used in an AJAX call for adding the next 5 posts. The call checks the amount of posts being displayed already and send that as an `$offset` parameter.

The `$args` for `query_posts` look like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_loadMore', 'loadMore');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadMore', 'loadMore');

function loadMore() {

    $posts_per_page = $_GET['posts_per_page'];
    $offset = $_GET['offset'];

    query_posts( 
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
            'post_type' => 'exhibitor',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'offset' => $offset
        )
    );

    ob_start();

        get_template_part('exhibitors-post-type/content', 'exhibitor');

    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    wp_reset_query();

    echo $output;

    die();

}
```

If I change `'order' => 'ASC'` to `'order' => 'DESC'` then everything works perfectly. It seems that something about `'order' => 'ASC'` breaks the `'offset'`.

I have tried this with `'orderby' => 'date'` and no `'orderby'` at all. Both produced the same issue.

UPDATE 09/07/2014 10:32AM ET

This is only happening during an AJAX call. It also only happens on the first request for 5 posts.

The AJAX call and JS that determines the offset is:

```
$posts_per_page = 5;
query_posts( 
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'post_type' => 'exhibitor',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title'
    )
);
global $wp_query; $found_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
?>

<?php 
get_template_part('exhibitors-post-type/content', 'exhibitor');
?>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var found_posts = <?php echo $found_posts; ?>;
        var posts_per_page = <?php echo $posts_per_page; ?>;
        var posts_on_page = $(".fullarticle").length;       
        $("#load-more").click(function() {
            posts_on_page = $(".fullarticle").length;
            if (posts_on_page === found_posts) {
                $("#load-more").text('No more posts!');
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'loadMore', posts_per_page: posts_per_page, offset: posts_on_page}),
                    success: function(results){
                        $('#fullcolumn').append(results);
                        if (posts_on_page === found_posts) {
                            $("#load-more").text('No more!');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>     

<button id="load-more" name="button">Load More</button>

</div><!-- End articlecontainer -->

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
        $('.discop-nav-menu-widget-form :checkbox').change(function() {
            var checkValues = $('.discop-nav-menu-widget-form input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
                return $(this).attr('name');
            }).get();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { action: 'exhibitor_ajax', ids: checkValues },
                success:function(result){
                    $('#the-results').empty();
                    $('#the-results').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You must know that [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) should not be used by plugins or themes because, most of the time, it alters the main query when it has been already executed. Use [`new WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) instead. Check using on of these functions and tell if it works. If not, please post the full code you are using, php and javascript.

Comment: @cybmeta, I updated my question with a little more information. I am modifying an existing theme that was using `query_posts`. I am aware of the common issues with this and attempted to change this to a `new WP_query` however that resulted in the AJAX call returning a 500 internal server error.